# EX16650 lost array

Tags: linux, raid

I have an EX16650 with 16 HDDs and a Raid 60.
Afer a fail of 1 disk we have to restard the system.
That ends in a huge problem.
After the reboot the controller found 0 HDDs.
Then we look in the bios of the controller.
0 HDD too.
then we have unplugged 3 of 4 HDD cable trees.
then we see again 4 HDDs.
we plugged each by each cable again.
then we saw all 16 drives again.
but we lost our array.
cliib> phydrv

```
PdId Model        Type       Capacity  Location      OpStatus   ConfigStatus

1    TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot1   OK         Unconfigured
2    Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot2   OK         Unconfigured
3    Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot3   OK         Unconfigured
4    TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot4   OK         Unconfigured
129  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot5   OK         Unconfigured
130  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot6   OK         Unconfigured
131  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot7   OK         Unconfigured
132  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot8   OK         Unconfigured
257  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot9   OK         Unconfigured
258  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot10  OK         Unconfigured
259  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot11  OK         Unconfigured
260  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot12  OK         Unconfigured
385  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot13  OK         Unconfigured
386  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot14  OK         Unconfigured
387  Hitachi HDS7 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot15  OK         Unconfigured
388  TOSHIBA DT01 SATA HDD   1.82TB    Encl1 Slot16  OK         Unconfigured
```

in the controller bios we dont find an option to import an old config from the disk.
anyone some idears how we can fix it and have our data back?

thanks for your help